# Wrong place - Tooltip Angular Material

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular-material, tooltip

I'm having a problem when using the tooltip provided by Angular Material (MatToolTip). As you can see in the attached image, when I place the cursor on the divs, the tooltip appears correctly, but not below the div, but on the left.

[image]

Here is my code in HTML:

```
  <div>
     <div style="float: left;width:10%"><span><p matTooltip="Tooltip test1">Test1</p></span></div>
     <div style="float: left;width:20%"><span><p matTooltip="Tooltip test2">Test2</p></span></div>
     <div style="float: left;width:30%"><span><p matTooltip="Tooltip test3">Test3</p></span></div>
     <div style="float: left;width:20%"><span><p matTooltip="Tooltip test4">Test4</p></span></div>
     <div style="float: left;width:20%"><span><p matTooltip="Tooltip test5">Test5</p></span></div>
  </div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just putting in what you have in you template seems to work as expected. Is it possible you have some other CSS causing this?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmwcie-rqckjb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Steps to find the tooltip and adjust its positioning.

1. Add [matTooltipHideDelay]="600000" so that the tooltip won't go away.
2. Find  which will contain your tooltip.
3. In my case, the header row had a bit of whitespace below the label, causing the tooltip to appear 3rem below the label and 0.75rem to the right.
4. Example style that helped my scenario:

```
/* mat-tooltip appear outside the :host */
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip.matTooltipTallHeaderCell {
  position: relative;
  left: -0.75rem;
  top: -3rem;
}
```